# Ideal less-than-or-equal circuit for multiple inputs?

Tags: digital-circuits, comparison

I'm interested in what the best way is to design a circuit that takes multiple values as input, and then outputs which value is the lowest. If multiple values are the lowest, it outputs "true" for each of them. Does anyone know an ideal design? For example, are there any classical "text-book examples" of one (or if someone has their own, it is also great. )

## My own effort

I came up with a circuit myself, but it is hard to know if it is actually a good design or just something "that works" but might be very inoptimal. It finds the lowest value by that each candidate submits bits only as long as they win for each bit (from highest to lowest) and "stay in the game". It then simply NANDs the bits submitted (for each bit height) to see if everyone had a one or if someone had a zero. Each candidate then checks if their value was higher than the submitted lowest value, and they will remove themselves from the game if they were (via the AND gates that flow from the OR:ed result of the NANDs. ) Each candidate that is the lowest value (also if there are multiple candidates with that value) will output true at "winner".

The schematic below shows it for four inputs each with four bit values.

[image]

This question is similar to a previous question I asked but focuses on the less-than-or-equal circuit while the other one was broader about interrupt controllers. Often better to ask precise, easy to answer questions. The schematic is also edited for this question, removing the "interrupt pending" option that was fed into the other schematic.

I asked previously about circuits here a year ago and got really good answers showing that my design was far from optimal, and learnt a lot. So doing another try here. I'm very interested in an answer, so that I can get better at circuit design.

Comment: I would not call this operator "less-than-or-equal", but rather "minimum" or "is-minimum".

Comment: might be a better term for it, good point

Comment: Besides an ad-hoc circuit, you can form a cascade of pairwise minimum operators, and after you have computed the global minimum, perform comparison for equality of all input numbers.

Comment: on a processor you mean? otherwise seems like it would require a lot more parts than my design. my interest in this is how modern interrupt controllers sort interrupts by priority, and I've assumed they use an ad hoc circuit for that and not a processor/software (why I tried to come up with how they might design it) but I could be wrong, really don't know where to search to find out if I am or not, probably because these things are usually proprietary

Comment: could be it uses microcode program when an interrupt occurs, and does the priority check. both work I guess. thanks for your feedback.

Comment: seems like it would require a lot more parts

Comment: seems like it to me, would you say it does not?

Comment: ok :) well thanks for your feedback, it made me consider that using the normal processor for this might not be the end of the world, just adds a little time before each interrupt handler runs. peace!

Comment: Another option is a 16 in/4 out PROM. :-)

Comment: that's a lot more parts. do you think that is a good solution?

Comment: How can we say without knowing your purpose ?

Comment: I'm interested in how interrupt controllers solve it, but this question asked about an ideal way to do "minimum" for multiple inputs. Using memory truth tables is not something I'd do myself. lots of parts, seems way unnecessary. but maybe you think it is a good solution, why I asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147478/discussion-between-bipedaljoe-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: You need at least three four-bit minimizers, which must be of a similar complexity as adders. So upon quick look I don't see too many gates in your design.

Comment: these platforms seem picky with not discussing, why I linked to a chat. my design does not use many parts, it NANDs all bits, then candidates remove themselves if someone had a zero but they did not, for each bit. this ensures the minimum value is found.

Comment: "best" is too vague to be a good fit here, and is a matter of opinion.  "best" by what metric?  There might be many possible designs, with different tradeoffs.  What exactly is the question?  We require you to articulate a specific question, where the question is clear and it is clear what criteria to use to evaluate answers, so that answerers can know in advance what types of answers are appropriate, and voters can know what criteria to use for evaluating answers.

Comment: a chat is opened to avoid long discussion. it is possible "best" is too vague, but not necessarily. as question says, maybe there are very common solutions to this, possibly also used in interrupt controllers, and maybe someone knows about that. it isn't a vague or far fetched thing to ask. there are often optimal solutions, and even if you want to optimize for different things there are trends that can be summarized.

Comment: to communicate so it should not be misunderstood: I have never designed a "find minimum of multiple values" circuit before, I have no experience with those. it is quite probable such circuits have been designed historically and that there are trends to what a good solution is. I did not ask about a truth table 16 in 4 out PROM, I asked about a circuit, so I did not ask a broad, vague question. I appreciate suggestions about PROMS too sure, maybe that is usually preferred (although I think not), but, my question was not about that, and not vague.

Comment: just close the question if you want. I disagree with that standardized circuits for "minimum out of multiple values" is not a computer science question, it seems as much a computer science question as how a circuit for addition is best designed, but in a community governed platform where three people can shut down questions I can't do much about that, nor would I ever design a system like that myself because it is a terrible idea, governance-wise